# VB.net transparent png overlaying each other.. getting Form Background color

Tags: vb.net, png, transparency

Trying to start a game that involve in a lot of .png and animation.

All these .png are already transparent and set to an individual picture box when i overlay one over the other. There "transparency" actually gets the form background color. and not i'm not able to see through the image behind it.

i set the forecolor to transparent in the attribute am i missing something?

*side question... should i make my game in vb.net if it using a lot of images and animations files? (working solo might get my friend to help later)

Example pictures
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: From searching the internet i found out that you can set the parent attribute of a picture box and it will get the transparent background of that image... but it still seems to be limited...

Answer (score 0):

well, this is a bit old, but check my answer here :

[Make Picturebox transparent over other picturebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967690/make-picturebox-transparent-over-other-picturebox-vb-net/14509179#14509179)